# Deleting duplicate elements in a array

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to delete duplicate elements in a array. There are lots of methods out there but I am trying to come up with my own one and tried the folllowing code.

```
x=[2,1,3,5,3,5]
for i in range(0,len(x)):
  for j in range(0,len(x)):
      if (x[i]==x[j+1]):
           del x[j+1]
for k in range(0,len(x)):
    print(x[k])
```

I get the following error at line 4
list index out of range.

Please help me!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating, the error comes from changing the length of the list while iterating over it

Comment: that is not an array, that is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors I can see:

1. You are using `j+1` in your program. When the second `for` loop reaches the end of the loop, `j` would equal `5`, and then `j+1` would equal `6`, but `x[6]` would be out of bounds.
2. Deleting the element from the array changes the length of the array. For example, your array starts with a length of `6`, but then, after one of the elements is deleted, it instead has a length `5`. However, the `for` loop doesn't recognize this, and still goes until `i=5` instead of stopping at `i=4`, and `x[5]` is out of bounds.